# Webpack renaming imported modules in transpiled test files

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

My test files are written in javascript but external modules are imported using es6 `import` syntax. However, when I transpile my test files using `awesome-typescript-loader`, the test files contains the imported module assigned to a different variable.

Hence, when I try to check any spy calls on the imported module's method in my tests, they fail. My guess is that the imported modules and the actual module which is called inside my `.ts` files are different. Any ideas what's happening?

My `webpac.karma.config` file used to transpile the test files is:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
    }]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/unittests/"
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ["node_modules"],
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
  }
};
```

My test file (example)...

```js
import { HELLO } from './hello';
describe('check', function(){
  it('should call friend method', function() {
    spyOn(HELLO, 'friend');
    $ctrl.methodThatCallsFriendMethod();
    expect(HELLO.friend).toHaveBeenCalled(); // This is not called
  });
})
```

In the transpiled test file inside unittests folder, the module is imported like this:

```js
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var hello_1 = __webpack_require__(5); // I fear this hello_1 does not reference to the same module imported in my main.ts file
...
...
describe('should call friend method', function() {
  it('should call friend method', function() {
    spyOn(hello_1.HELLO, 'friend');
    $ctrl.methodThatCallsFriendMethod();
    expect(hello_1.HELLO.friend).toHaveBeenCalled(); // This is not called
  });
});
```

My HELLO module is very simple:

```js
export class Hello {
  static friend() {
    return 'dneirf;
  }
}
```

In my main ts file, I import the `HELLO` module normally (`import {HELLO} from ...`) and all works fine. It just doesn't work in test files. Thanks for any suggestions.